# Pass Value of clicked button from one page to another page Input field

Tags: php, javascript

Weird question this, going round in circles.

I have 2 pages.

Page 1. Has a button on it. Like

```
<form action="goto_page_2.php"><p class="longdesc"><span class="spanBold">Scrap Collections in North Lakes:</span><br />
      <button class="readViewMoreBtn" value="North Lakes">Book a Collection in North Lakes</button>
      </p></form>
```

The above is a simple mockup. But what I want to do is, onclick of the button, parse the Value to ...

Page 2. Which has a form built in.

One of the fields is Suburb.

```
<!-- EMAIL SUBURB -->            
                <span class="commonControlLabel">Suburb:</span>&nbsp;
                <span class="commonControlLabelItalic">(required)</span>
                <span id="contactSuburbErrorMsg" class="commonControlErrorMsg"></span><br />
                <input class="commonInput" type="text" id="inputSuburb" value=""/><br />
```

So what I want to do, is grab the VALUE of the button on PAGE 1, and add it to the Value in the input element on Page 2.

To complicate matters, Page 1. Has quite a few buttons, with different values, all unique, which we would like to pass, to the input element. Obviously onlcick of the button on page 1 we go direct to page 2.

Comment: Are all the buttons on the same form? Also are using jQuery? And how does the form get submitted. Just a plain old html request?

Comment: If you have two different page and want the button click take the value from one page to another, then its not possible as it needs a server side connection when moving from one page to another if you want to use the value in another page

Comment: I could assign each suburb a var and declare that on both pages. The page 1 uses form tags round each button element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the button post it's value to Page2:

Page1, I added `type="submit"` and `name="suburb"`

```
<button type="submit" name="suburb" class="readViewMoreBtn" value="North Lakes">Book a Collection in North Lakes</button>
```

Page2: I added the php part in the value attribute

```
<input class="commonInput" type="text" id="inputSuburb" value="<?= $_POST['suburb'] ?>"/>
```

Comment: Its not passing the value across. Bugger

Comment: Wondering if we could use html5 ?

Comment: I am such a KNOB, i forgot to add method="post" works ace thankyou

Comment: haha yeah a form without post doesn't really post that much. :) Glad you managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--page1::-->
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test2.php" method="post">
            <button name="desc" value="1">description!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<!--page2::-->

<?php
    echo "hello";
    echo $_POST["desc"];
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do.

E.g: on form 2 say:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['inputNameForm1'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['inputNameForm1']);} ?>
```

Or if that is not an option for you, try something like:

```
<? php

session_start();

$_SESSION['sessionName'] = $_POST['inputNameForm1']?>

<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['sessionName']])){echo htmlentities($_SESSION['sessionName']]);} ?> />
```

Note: didn't test the code